# Un-"jQuery $.param" in Server Side Python (GAE)

Tags: jquery, python, json, google-app-engine, http-post

I'm using jQuery's `$.post()` method to post JSON data, specifically I'm posting an array.

```
$.post('/my/url/',{my_list:['foo','bar','foo baz']})
```

I've read in the docs that the `post` method will use the `$.param` method to serialize JSON objects given to it as data. The jQuery docs seem to imply that their method of serialization is an oft-used standard (at least in Ruby on Rails and PHP), but I can't seem to find any convenient modules/methods that automagically un-serialize `$.param` in Python.

What's the easiest way to un-`param-`aterize this data in Python? More specifically, I'm using Google App Engine.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Added `my_list` key to data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [JQuery `$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) sends url-encoded form variables to the server, not JSON key-values.  So this:

```
$.post('/foo', {foo: "bar", nums: [1, 2, 3]})
```

Results in the following `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data being posted 
to `/foo`:

```
foo=bar&nums%5B%5D=1&nums%5B%5D=2&nums%5B%5D=3
```

Which you can parse in Python using [`urlparse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.parse_qs('foo=bar&nums%5B%5D=1&nums%5B%5D=2&nums%5B%5D=3')
{'foo': ['bar'], 'nums[]': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

Comment: Well, he's sending an array, not separate values.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out!

In Google App Engine in particular the `get_all` method of the `Request` object handles JSON arrays serialized with jQuery's `.param` method.

The slightly confusing part is that jQuery tacks `[]` on to the end of the parameter key. As such, the Python code which you use is...

```
class MyListHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print self.request.get_all('my_list[]') # <-- Note the `[]`
```

...this will print...

```
[u'foo', u'bar', u'foo baz']
```

Answer (score 2):

[jquery-unparam](https://bitbucket.org/k_bx/jquery-unparam) handles nested data structures better than urlparse!  E.g.:

```
// as produced by $.get, $.post etc
$.param({a: 1, b: [2,3,4], c: { d: 5 } })
"a=1&b%5B%5D=2&b%5B%5D=3&b%5B%5D=4&c%5Bd%5D=5"
```

Python by jquery_unparam vs. urlparse.parse_qs:

```
>>> from jquery_unparam import jquery_unparam
>>> jquery_unparam("a=1&b%5B%5D=2&b%5B%5D=3&b%5B%5D=4&c%5Bd%5D=5")
{'a': '1', 'c': {'d': '5'}, 'b': ['2', '3', '4']}

>>> from urlparse import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs("a=1&b%5B%5D=2&b%5B%5D=3&b%5B%5D=4&c%5Bd%5D=5")
{'a': ['1'], 'b[]': ['2', '3', '4'], 'c[d]': ['5']}
```